Traefik on EKS propagating 499 to the Service
It's possible configure the traefik ingress to propagate the close connection (499) to the service associated?
My backend is a spring boot java and I want know if the connection is closed to interrupt a processing.
With docker-compose this behavior happens very well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
